# Adding multiple members in Microsoft Teams through Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I am administrating multiple users as members to Microsoft Teams through [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-unifiedgrouplinks?view=exchange-ps), following [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_tfe-msteams_chatg-msteams_suboth/how-to-add-multiple-members-at-the-same-time-in/ccf20146-12db-454f-93b2-37cb59aa5858).

Users are getting added in Office 365 groups, and are reflected in Microsoft Teams admin center at the same time.  However, users aren't reflected in MS Teams (https://teams.microsoft.com/) even after 24 hours.

Also, I don't have any other way to automate adding users to MS Teams.

Answer (score 2):

Please use [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgrouplinks?view=exchange-ps) to get the members for group

However, users aren't reflected in MS Teams (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/) even after 24 hours

are you referring  MS Teams client, request you to check in web and desktop client

Please use [Teams cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/add-teamuser?view=teams-ps) to add members to Teams

Thank You,
Geetha Doli.

Comment: lil correction. user are not reflecting in https://teams.microsoft.com/ , neither on web nor on desktop client.
how can i pass multiple members to Add-TeamUser , i just want to pass user value ,not through .csv

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft teams are built on top of Office365 environment. Please use below cmdlet to add user to teams as members
Add-TeamUser -GroupId 31f1ff6c-d48c-4f8a-b2e1-abca7fd399df -User dmx@example.com

please go through below links to add members to team
[link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/add-teamuser?view=teams-ps)
[link2](http://www.ntweekly.com/2020/03/14/add-multiple-users-to-a-microsoft-teams-team-using-powershell/)